# How to nest sed substitutions?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a rather huge tab separated text file (larger than 8 GB). There are some lines that have extra tabs between some fields, and I'd like to replace these tabs with space using the pattern:

```
'android(\t.*)+android'
```

However, this requires nested substitutions using `sed.exe`. Is there a nice solution to this problem?

Below are my demo data, in line 1, there are 4 extra tabs between `Android*Android` which need to be eliminated.

```
1   372C00365B22        103 20150423135612  Android 2.3 wzapp   3.1.0   Android 5   200 1
2   372C00365B23        103 20150424175612  IOS 2   200 1
13  372C005EB183        103 20150423231051  Agoo-sdk-2.0    0       6       1
```

Comment: In general, if you feel you need to do crazy sed things like nesting expressions, you should probably be using ruby or python to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a higher-level language to break up the input in three parts, then just replace tabs in the middle part.

```
awk -F 'android' 'NF==3 { gsub(/\t/, " ", $2) }1' input
```

This attempts to split each input line on "android" as if it were the field separator; then substitutes all tabs with spaces in the middle part only when there are exactly three parts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're saying with replacing multiple tabs.

If you're simply saying you want to replace multiple tabs with a single space any time they are encountered, this should suffice:

```
cat file | sed 's|[[:blank:]]\{1,\}| |g'
```

If you want to change multiple tabs into a single tab, this should do:

```
cat file | sed "s|[[:blank:]]\\{1,\\}|$(printf '\t')|g"
```

If by your question you mean you need to apply one sed expression after the other, that is also doable:

```
cat file | sed -e "s|expr1|expression1|g" -e "s|expr2|expression2|g"
```

Both expressions will be applied to the line, one after the other. This way you can make a substitution, then a substitution on that substitution.

See the [docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sed.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to nest substitutions but this may not be the fastest way. It also may not work if you have more `android`s on a line (and you have no anchor to fix on a single pair):

```
sed ':l s/\(android.*\)\t\t\t*\(.*android\)/\1\t\2/;tl' input
```